# How to know if extglob is enabled in the current bash session?

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a bash terminal open. I want to find out whether the option extglob is enabled or disabled in this session, before I change its value. How can I do this?

Comment: Note that there's no need to check unless you're curious. If you want it on, just run `shopt -s extglob` or, if you want it off, run `shopt -u extglob`. It doesn't make any difference whatsoever if it was on originally or not.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just run:

```
$ shopt extglob
```

It will return the current status:

```
$ shopt extglob 
extglob         on
$ shopt -u extglob 
$ shopt extglob 
extglob         off
```

To show all options, just run:

```
$ shopt
```

Comment: This one can also be used for scripting, its return status also indicate option set or unset, but the message will mess standard out.

Answer (score 13):

Use [shopt -q](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-shopt):

```
shopt -q extglob && echo enable || echo disable
```

`-q` option make `shopt` discard output, and return status to indicate that options set or unset.

Note that `shopt` only reports options which can appear in `BASHOPTS` variable, those options are not valid to `set` builtin command.

To check for options which are valid to `set`, or can be appear in `SHELLOPTS`, use `shopt -qo`:

```
$ bash --posix -c 'shopt -qo posix && echo enable || echo disable'
enable
```

Comment: Why not just `shopt extglob`?

Comment: Because I don't want the output to mess my standard out :)

Comment: What do you mean? As far as I can tell, the OP wants to check whether the option is set or not. They mention that this is in a terminal, so I doubt it's part of a script. And, anyway, what's the difference? Both `shopt extglob` and your approach will write to stdout. Are you thinking of `shopt -q extglob && shopt -u extglob || shopt -s extglob`?

Comment: @terdon: Well, my approach only write to stdout *if I want*. The general approach is `shopt -q extglob && : Code when enable || : Code when disable`.

Comment: OK, I just don't really see why that would be useful. You can always simply run `shopt -s extglob` to enable (or `shopt -u extglob`) to disable. It doesn't matter whether it was on or off originally. No error (or output) is printed if you run `shopt -s extglob` and it was already enabled. That's why I couldn't understand your suggestion here.

Comment: @terdon: Fair point. TIMTOWTDI!

Comment: I can imagine writing a script that would attempt to preserve the user's existing setting, but might have a critical bit of code that will break if it's not set a particular way.  This suggests a method to silently determine the current state, save it, and restore it ASAP after performing the crucial operations that require potentially-different state.

Answer (score 8):

There are two lists of options in bash. One for `shopt` and one for `set`.

The option `extglob` belongs to the `shopt` list.
Its value may be printed by using either `shopt extglob` or `shopt -p extglob`.

An option like `nounset` belongs to the `set` list.
Its value may be printed by using `shopt -op nounset` or `shopt -o nounset`.

#### Check one option.

To print an specific option (without changing it) for shopt, use `shopt -p name`:

```
$ shopt -p xpg_echo
shopt -u xpg_echo
```

And for `set`, use: `shopt -po name` (yes, you may use `shopt -op` for `set` list).

```
$  shopt -po xtrace
set +o xtrace
```

#### List options.

To list all options from shopt, use `shopt` (or reusable `shopt -p`).
Also `shopt -s` or `shopt -u` could be used.

The way to list all options to `set` is with `set -o` (related: `set +o`).
Or: `shopt -o` is equivalent to `set -o` and `shopt -op` is to `set +o`.

#### Manual

From `LESS=+/'^ *shopt \[' man bash`:

> With no options, or with the -p option, a list of all settable options is displayed,
>   If  either  -s  or  -u  is  used  with no optname arguments, the display is limited to those options which are set or unset, respectively.

From `LESS=+/'^ *set \[' man bash`:

> If -o is supplied with no option-name, the values of the current options are printed. If +o is supplied with no option-name, a series of set commands  to  recreate the current option settings is displayed on the standard output.

#### Examples

```
$ set -o
allexport       off
braceexpand     on
emacs           on
errexit         off
errtrace        off
functrace       off
hashall         on
histexpand      on
history         on
ignoreeof       off
interactive-comments    on
keyword         off
monitor         on
noclobber       off
noexec          off
noglob          off
nolog           off
notify          off
nounset         off
onecmd          off
physical        off
pipefail        off
posix           off
privileged      off
verbose         off
vi              off
xtrace          off
```

And

```
$  shopt -sp
shopt -s checkwinsize
shopt -s cmdhist
shopt -s expand_aliases
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s extquote
shopt -s force_fignore
shopt -s histappend
shopt -s histverify
shopt -s interactive_comments
shopt -s progcomp
shopt -s promptvars
shopt -s sourcepath
```

It is worth mentioning about `shopt -op` which actually lists `set` options:

```
$ shopt -op
set +o allexport
set -o braceexpand
set -o emacs
set +o errexit
set +o errtrace
set +o functrace
set -o hashall
set -o histexpand
set -o history
set +o ignoreeof
set -o interactive-comments
set +o keyword
set -o monitor
set +o noclobber
set +o noexec
set +o noglob
set +o nolog
set +o notify
set +o nounset
set +o onecmd
set +o physical
set +o pipefail
set +o posix
set +o privileged
set +o verbose
set +o vi
set +o xtrace
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer [given above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269859/105631), for `set` flags,

> The current set of flags may be found in $-.

(source: bash help)

```
if [[ ${-%x*} != $- ]] ; then echo "Debug (xtrace) is on"; fi
```

Comment: The question is about `extglob` which in the context of the answer you linked to "belongs to the `shopt` list". The linked answer is kind enough to cover the "`set` list", but what counts is it covers the "`shop` list" and therefore can be used to know about `extglob`. So it answers the question. Your answer alone does not answer the question because `extglob` is not a "`set` flag" and its state does not affect `$-`. If the question was about Bash options in general then your answer would fit. The question is specific, so IMO your "answer" should be a comment or an edit to the linked answer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you for that detailed critique, but ... did you read my answer? Line 1: _Adding to the answer_ (link given). Perhaps it would have been better if I had edited the answer.  I'm not here for upvotes. I'm here for utility. Comments are not useful for providing answers, only remarking on them.

Comment: My point is your answer does not answer *the* question. Each answer should be standalone. "Adding to another answer" is allowed if what you add *also* answers the question. Possibly if what you add expands a fragment (of the other answer) that answers the question. Your answer expands a fragment that does not answer the question. The fragment is there as something extra next to a fragment that does. I still think your "answer" does not fit the Q&A scheme, it should be a comment or an edit to the linked answer. But I'm not on a crusade; I have stated my opinion and now I'm going to pass.