# Check for bash options

Tags: bash, shopt

I have a function and would like to use the `pipefail` option inside. But I don't want to simply `set -o pipefail`, because I fear that another part of the script may not expect `pipefail` to be set. Of course I could do `set +o pipefail` afterwards, but in case `pipefail` was set outside of my function, this may introduce unexpected behavior as well.

Of course I could use the exit code of `false | true` as a measure, if `pipefail` is set, but this seems a little bit dirty.

Is there a more general (and maybe canonical?) way to check the set bash options?

Comment: There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12179633/1331399) by me on SO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `$SHELLOPTS` variable holds all set options separated by colons. As an example, it may look like:

```
braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor
```

To check for a given option one may do the following:

```
# check if pipefail is set, if not set it and remember this
if [[ ! "$SHELLOPTS" =~ "pipefail" ]]; then
    set -o pipefail;
    PIPEFAIL=0;
else
    PIPEFAIL=1;
fi

# do something here

# reset pipefail, if it was not set before
if [ "$PIPEFAIL" -eq 0 ]; then
    set +o pipefail;
fi
```

Comment: Note that `bash` has 2 sets of options (for no good reason, no other Bourne-like shell does that), one you set with `set -o` and seen in `$SHELLOPTS` and one you set with `shopt -s` (and seen in `$BASHOPTS`).

Comment: See also `[[ -o pipefail ]]` to test if the (`$SHELLOPTS`) `pipefail` option is set. Also works in ksh and zsh

Comment: `shopt -q globstar` to query the state of a `shopt`/`$BASHOPTS` option

Answer (score 12):

In `bash-4.4` and above, you can use:

```
myfunction() {
  local -
  set -o someoption
  ...
}
```

A few notes:

- that's copied from `ash`. In `ash`, the idea is to make `$-` (which stores the set of options) local. It works in `ash` because in `ash`, `local` doesn't affect the value nor attributes of the variable (contrary to `bash` where it initially makes it unset). Still it also works with `bash` the same way as in `ash` as a special case, that is it doesn't cause `$-` to be unset or revert to a default behaviour
- it only covers the options set with `set -o option`, not the ones set by `shopt -s option` (`bash` being the only shell with two sets of options!)
- like for local variables,  it is dynamic scoping, not static. The value of `$-` will be restored upon returning from the function, but the new setting will affect the other functions or sourced scripts called by your function. If you want static scoping, you'll need to switch to ksh93 and use:

  ```
  function myfunction {
    set -o myoption
    ...
    other_function
  }
  ```

  With the `other_function` not affected as long as it's declared with the `function other_function {` syntax as well (and not the Bourne `other_function()...` syntax).
- As it doesn't reset the options, your function may still be affected by options set by other code. To avoid that, you'd want to use `zsh` instead. `zsh`'s equivalent of `local -` is `set -o localoptions`, but you can also get to a well known *emulation* mode *locally*. For instance:

  ```
  myfunction() {
    emulate -L zsh
    set -o someoption
    ...
  }
  ```

  would start with a sane zsh-default set of options (with some exceptions, see doc) on top of which you add your option. That's also dynamic scoping like in ash/bash, but you can also call other functions with:

  ```
  emulate zsh -c 'other_function...'
  ```

  for that `other_function` to be called with a vanilla zsh option set.

  zsh also has a number of operators that can make you avoid changing options globally in the first place (like `(N)`/`(D)` glob qualifiers for `nullglob`/`dotglob`, `(#i)` glob operator for case insensitive globbing, `${(s:x:)var}` to avoid mingling with `$IFS`, `${~var}` to *request* globbing upon parameter expansion (you need `noglob` in other Bourne-like shells to *avoid* (!) it)...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set a shell option inside a function, but do not want to affect the caller, you do it two different ways:

### Option 1: subshell

Put the function inside a subshell (notice the parenthesis surrounding the function's statements instead of curly brackets):

```
function foo() (
  set -o pipefail
  echo inside foo
  shopt -o pipefail
  # ...
)
```

Then, the caller can have pipefail unset and is not affected:

```
$ shopt -o pipefail
pipefail        off
$ foo
inside foo
pipefail        on
$ shopt -o pipefail
pipefail        off
```

or

### Option 2: test-and-reset

You could test-and-reset the option as needed (notice the curly braces around the function statements -- no subshell):

```
function foo() {
  shopt -q -o pipefail
  local resetpipefail=$?
  set -o pipefail
  echo inside foo
  shopt -o pipefail
  # ...
  # only reset pipefail if needed
  [[ $resetpipefail -eq 1 ]] && set +o pipefail  
}

$ shopt -o pipefail
pipefail        off
$ foo
inside foo
pipefail        on
$ shopt -o pipefail
pipefail        off
```

Hat tip to [cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/38906/cuonglm) for their [`shopt -q` answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255341/117549).

Answer (score 2):

## Use a RETURN trap

> Commands specified with an `RETURN` trap are executed before execution resumes after a shell function or a shell script executed with `.` or `source` returns.
>
> [...]
> The `-p` option [to shopt] causes output to be displayed in a form that may be reused as input.
>
> – https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

```
foo() {
  trap "$(shopt -p -o pipefail)" RETURN
  set -o pipefail
  echo inside foo
  shopt -o pipefail
  # ...
}
```

Test

```
$ shopt -o pipefail
pipefail        off
$ foo
inside foo
pipefail        on
$ shopt -o pipefail
pipefail        off
```

The following function template handles the general case of ensuring that both `set` and `shopt` options are restored to their original values when a function returns:

```
foo() {
  trap "$(shopt -p -o; shopt -p)" RETURN # ①
  # ...
}
```

① `shopt -p -o` can be simplified to the standard equivalent `set +o`.

Answer (score 2):

The following uses `bash`'s `-o` test to test whether the `pipefail` shell option is set or not (this works in `[[ ... ]]` and with the `test` built-in command, but not with `[ ... ]`).  If the option isn't set, it sets it and installs a trap that will unset it when the function returns:

```
foo () {
    if [[ ! -o pipefail ]]; then
        set -o pipefail
        trap 'set +o pipefail' RETURN
    fi

    # rest of function body
}
```

Code with some debugging included:

```
foo () {
    if [[ ! -o pipefail ]]; then
        set -o pipefail
        trap 'set +o pipefail' RETURN
    fi

    # rest of function body
    if [[ -o pipefail ]]; then
        echo 'pipefail is set (in function)'
    else
        echo 'pipefail is not set (in function)'
    fi
}

if [[ -o pipefail ]]; then
    echo 'pipefail is set'
else
    echo 'pipefail is not set'
fi

foo

if [[ -o pipefail ]]; then
    echo 'pipefail is set'
else
    echo 'pipefail is not set'
fi
```

Running it:

```
$ bash script.sh
pipefail is not set
pipefail is set (in function)
pipefail is not set

$ bash -o pipefail script.sh
pipefail is set
pipefail is set (in function)
pipefail is set
```