# How to test if a folder exists using regular expression in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, regular-expression

as all know we can check easily if folder exists by the following bash command

```
[[ -d /opt/presto-server ]] && echo folder exist
```

but when we have folder as

```
/opt/presto-server-32.34
```

then how to use regular expression in order to validate that folder is exists

with this rule

```
presto-server-<any charecter>
```

as

```
presto-server-454.545
presto-server-4a-434
presto-server-aa-434-l
```

etc

Comment: you say "re" for regular expression, but you don't *actually* need a regex, right? Your test is "any character" -- so you don't care what those following characters *are*?  Does there need to be a dash between `presto-server` and the remainder?

Comment: yes dash is between presto-server to any character

Comment: What about find with regexp ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19840606/912046

Comment: yes But I ask with bash not by find command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would count how many parameters resulted from the expansion of a wildcard. First, I would set `nullglob` so that if there are no matches, we get the expected zero instead of the wildcard itself.

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Then ask for the expansion of the desired pattern and set them as the current parameters:

```
set -- /opt/presto-server-*/
```

Note the addition of the trailing slash -- that requires that the resulting matches are directories (or symlinks to directories).

Then ask how many there are:

```
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && echo "There are one or more presto-server- directories"
```

Comment: but if for example presto-server-  , is file and not folder , then its not so good

Comment: @yael, that's why I put the trailing slash on the wildcard; files won't match.

Comment: how to return back the - shopt -s nullglob  ( as was before )

Comment: Depending on your overall goal, you could use a subshell or one of these questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255338/117549 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/406216/117549 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/310957/117549

Comment: If you're sure that you usually have it *unset*, though, you could juset `shopt -u nullglob` at the end.

Comment: Another way is to not use `shopt` at all, then do the `set` and test whether `$1` is a directory. Would work in `/bin/sh` too then.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a function `has_dirs` like:

```
has_dirs() {
  for f do
    [ -d "$f" ] && return
  done
  false
}
```

And use it as:

```
if has_dirs /opt/presto-server-*; then
  echo there are matching dirs
fi
```

That's for directories or symlinks to directories. For directories only, you'd need:

```
    [ -d "$f" ] && [ ! -L "$f" ] && return
```

To more specifically match on `prestor-server-<number>-<number>`, with `bash`, you can do:

```
shopt -s extglob # to enable a subset of ksh extended globs
has_dirs /opt/presto-server-+([[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]])
```

Though beware that it could give a false positive it there was a directory called literally `/opt/presto-server-+([[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]])` (the `failglob` or `nullglob` options can work around that).

Answer (score 1):

If switching to `zsh` is an option:

```
if ()(($# > 0)) /opt/presto-server-*(N/); then
  echo there are directories matching that pattern
fi
```

Where

- `() compound-command args` is an anonymous function with arguments
- `((...))`: compound command that evaluates the `...` arithmetic expression and returns *success* if it results in a number other  than 0.
- `$# > 0`: arithmetic expression that evaluates to 1 if `$#` (the number of arguments to that anonymous function) is greater than 0.
- `(N/)`: glob qualifiers: `N` to turn on `nullglob` for that one glob, `/` to only select the files of type *directory* (change to `-/` to also include symlinks to directories).

That's not terribly efficient as that computes the whole list of directories (for which `zsh` needs to do a `lstat()` on each matching file) which are later sorted, while finding just one directory would have been sufficient.

You can change `*` to `<->-<->` to specifically match a sequence of numbers separated by `-`.

Of course, within `bash`, you can always do:

```
if zsh -c '()(($# > 0)) /opt/presto-server-<->-<->(N/)'; then
  echo there are directories matching that pattern
fi
```

Comment: what in  case we need to run it in bash not in zsh?